# ASP.NET MVC Preview 5 - Html.Image helper has moved namespace

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, html-helper

We've just updated ASP.NET from Preview 3 to Preview 5 and we've run into a problem with the `Html.Image` HtmlHelper in our aspx pages.

It seems that `Html.Image` has moved from `System.Web.Mvc` into `Microsoft.Web.Mvc`, and the only way we've found to access the helper now is to add an import statement to every .aspx page that uses it. All the other helpers can be accessed with `using System.Web.Mvc;` in the C# codebehind of a view master page, but this one seems to need an `<@Import Namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc">` in every .aspx page.

Does anyone know of a way around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add the namespace to pages in System.Web in you web config.

```
<pages validateRequest="false">
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc"/>        
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```